# Consuming lazy-loaded Angular 2 components in a template constructed from an external JSON file

Tags: javascript, angular, autoload, angular2-template

I'm building an angular components doc/demo site that enumerates a list of Angular components and a set of JSON documents with usage details and examples.

Here's an example of a basic component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-button',
    template: `<button class="btn btn-default">I am a banana</button>`
})
export class Button {}
```

To start with, I'm using a pre-build script to autogenerate a `componentLoader` file that looks like this:

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Button } from '../app/components/elements/button/button';

export const COMPONENT_ROUTES: Route[] = [{ path: 'button', component: Button }];
export const COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS: Array<any|any[]> = [Button];
```

I then load that into `app.module.ts` (removed other imports for brevity):

```
import { COMPONENT_ROUTES, COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS } from './componentLoader';
// ...
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [ ... ].concat(COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS)
```

This works fine; I can use the button in a view component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'button-test',
    template: `
    <my-button></my-button>
`
})
export class ButtonTest {}
```

Woo!

Now, I want need be able to enumerate a folder of JSON documents to look for details related to this component and how it's used. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "button",
    "description": "An example of an 'I am a banana' button",
    "exampleHTML": "<div><my-button></my-button></div>"
}
```

Notice how in `exampleHTML` I'm trying to *use* the component we loaded in the `componentLoader`.

To generate doc views, I built a docs service that takes an `id` param and searches for a matching JSON document in the /docs dir:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

declare const require: any;

@Injectable()

export class DocsService {
    constructor() { }
    getDoc(id: string) {
        const json: string = require('../docs/' + id + '.json');
        return json;
    }   
}
```

Then the detail component imports the service and consumes the JSON doc component in the template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }    from '@angular/router';
import { DocsService } from '../../services/docs.service';

declare const require: any;
const template: string = require('./componentDetail.html');

@Component({
    selector: 'componentDetail',
    template: `<div>Name: {{componentDoc.name}}</div>
               Examples:<br><br><div [innerHTML]="componentExample"></div>`
})

export class ComponentDetail {

    public componentDoc: any
    private _componentExample: string
    public get componentExample(): SafeHtml {
       return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._componentExample);
    }

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private docsService: DocsService,
        private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {         
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
          if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
            let id = params['id'];
            this.componentDoc = this.docsService.getDoc(id)
            this._componentExample = this.componentDoc.exampleHTML
          } else { throw Error('Not found') }
        });
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

Perhaps because of the way these components are loaded, or because I'm not loading HTML into Angular's templating engine correctly, or because there's a black-box Webpack service that runs in the middle of the build chain, the template that *should* show the actual `button` component, is completely blank.

In the component detail view, I can manually set the template string to `<my-button></my-button>` and it works, but it doesn't when I try to load it from the JSON doc.

**How can I get the detail component to actually render the Button *component* used in the JSON doc?**

Comment: Would it be correct to rephrase your question as "how to compile a piece of markup dynamically"? (Just trying to figure if I understood your question)

Comment: I suppose, yes. But specifically markup that uses an Angular component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See working Plnkr Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JGwFygtcnr242EL6A60I)

Instead of using the `[innerHTML]` directive you can instead attack the problem by creating dynamic components.

To do so you will need to use the [Compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Compiler-class.html) method to dynamically load a Module and its components.

First you will need to create a module that contains your applications components that you want to be able to use within the dynamic HTML.

Change your `componentLoader` to be a module like so

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Button } from '../../app/components/elements/button/button';

const COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS: Array<any|any[]> = [
    Button
];

@NgModule({ 
    declarations: COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS, 
    exports: COMPONENT_DECLARATIONS, 
    imports: [CommonModule] 
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Create `dynamicComponent.service.ts` that will be used to generate the dynamic modules and components. The key to using components within the dynamically loaded HTML is how we will import the `ComponentsModule` within `DynamicComponentModule`.

```
import { 
  Component,
  Compiler,
  ModuleWithComponentFactories,
  ComponentFactory,  
  NgModule,
  Type
} from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable }                from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }              from '@angular/common';

import { ComponentsModule }          from '../components/components.module';

@Injectable()
export class DynamicComponentService {

  private componentFactoriesCache: ComponentFactory<any>[] = [];  

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) { }

  public getComponentFactory(templateHtml: string): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    return new Promise<ComponentFactory<any>>((resolve) => {
        let factory = this.componentFactoriesCache[templateHtml];
        if ( factory ) { 
            resolve(factory);
        } else {
            let dynamicComponentType = this.createDynamicComponent(templateHtml);
            let dynamicModule = this.createDynamicModule(dynamicComponentType);

            this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(dynamicModule)
                .then((mwcf: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
                    factory = mwcf.componentFactories.find(cf => cf.componentType === dynamicComponentType);
                    this.componentFactoriesCache[templateHtml] = factory;
                    resolve(factory);
            });
        }
     });
  }

  private createDynamicComponent(templateHtml: string): Type<NgModule> {
    @Component({
      template: templateHtml,
    })
    class DynamicDocComponent {}

    return DynamicDocComponent;
  }

  private createDynamicModule(dynamicComponentType: Type<Component>) {
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [dynamicComponentType],
      imports: [CommonModule, ComponentsModule]
    })
    class DynamicDocComponentModule {}

    return DynamicDocComponentModule;
  }

}
```

Import `ComponentsModule` and `DynamicComponentService` into `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [        
        ...
        ComponentsModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
        DynamicComponentService
    ]
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Finally the `ComponentDetail` is changed to use the new `DynamicComponentService` to get the `ComponentFactory` for the dynamic component.

Once you have the new `ComponentFactory` you can then use a view container to create and populate the component with the dynamic html.

```
import { 
  Component,  
  ComponentRef,
  ViewChild,   
  ViewContainerRef, 
  AfterContentInit,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }    from '@angular/router';

import { DocsService }               from './services/docs.service';
import { DynamicComponentService }   from './services/dynamicComponent.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'componentDetail',
  template:  `<div>Name: {{componentDoc.name}}</div>
               Examples:<br><br><template #container></template>
  `
})

export class ComponentDetail implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {

  private componentRouteID: string;
  private componentDoc: any;
  private componentExampleHtml: string;
  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) 
  private container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private docsService: DocsService,
              private dynamicComponentService: DynamicComponentService) {
      this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
          this.componentRouteID = params['id'];
          if (this.componentRouteID ) {
              this.componentDoc = this.docsService.getDoc(this.componentRouteID);            
              this.componentExampleHtml = this.componentDoc.exampleHTML;
          } else {
             throw Error('Not found'); 
          }
        });
  }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dynamicComponentService.getComponentFactory(this.componentExampleHtml).then((factory) => {
        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);        
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {    
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }
}
```